# Oracle Error- ORA-28374: typed master key not found in wallet

Tags: java, oracle, oracle12c

I'm using Spring Boot with Hikari Thread pool to connect to an Oracle 12c DB. All my tables are created in encrypted tablespaces. The issue is that randomly, when I try to get a connection to my DB, I get the exception below.

```
java.sql.SQLException ORA-28374: typed master key not found in wallet 
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:392)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:385)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1018)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:501)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:437)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:954)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:639)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117)
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123)
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:367)
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:196)
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467)
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.access$100(HikariPool.java:71)
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:706)
      at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolEntryCreator.call(HikariPool.java:692)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As you can see, the ojdbc driver is what throws the error. Here's what I've tried so far.

- Check DB logs. The DBA's don't see any errors in their logs. (EDIT : Turns out that they made a mistake and eventually informed me that they did see the issue on their logs)
- Upgrade my ojdbc6.jar driver. Issue still persists.
- Re-create the entire DB. Still happens.
- Test by creating my tables in an unencrypted tablespace. This resolves the issue, but it's company policy to have encrypted tablespaces.
- Used SQLcl to query the DB. I still have this error showing up even with SQLcl! SQLcl uses ojdbc8.jar driver to connect.

Could this be something where the key rotation policy is incorrectly configured by the DBAs? The sad part is that I don't control the DB resources so I can't debug the DB side from my end, I have to talk to a remote DBA. Any clues are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was a setup issue on the DB side. Our DBAs informed us that in our Oracle cluster, the wallet file was not copied on all nodes. This means that if our application tried connecting to a node that did not have a corresponding wallet, it would throw the ORA-28374 error.